# JQuery Mobile changePage alternative doesn't use transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a page that allows users to use a swipe gesture to navigate the pages. I am able to get this working but I can not use the native jQM method, changePage. I can't use changePage because we generate URL's for the next page dynamically. Here is the working script:

```
$(function(){
  $('#page_div').live('swiperight', function(event){
location.href='/<?= $this->nextSlideLink ?>';
});
  $('#page_div').live('swipeleft', function(event){
location.href='/<?= $this->prevSlideLink ?>';
  });
});
```

Now, the problem is that i'm not able to get the jQM transitions functioning because i'm not using changePage.

Normally you would do something like this, but not in this instance:

```
$('#page_div').live('swiperight', function(event){
$mobile.changePage('<?= $this->prevSlideLink ?>' {transition:'slide'});
 });
```

Does anyone know how I can get the transitions working??

Comment: I don't get why you are not able to use a dynamic url. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using changePage ??

If you really need to avoid changePage, you could try to emulate a click:

```
jQuery('<a href="<?= $this->prevSlideLink ?>"/>')
    .appendTo(jQuery.mobile.activePage)
    .trigger('click')
    .remove();
```